# XSLT match all nodes & Ignore a specific node

Tags: templates, xslt

I have an XSLT and i wanted to copy all the elements under a specific node with the exception of one particular node. The reason i am ignoring this node is, i need to check if node exists in xml & if it doesn't then i need to set a default value. Here is the code snipette i have & it doesn't seem to work

I have couple other templates in XSLT &  i included mode so i can specifically use this for a particular node

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="copyexcludingDL">
     <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::DriversLicense)]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is the Node & the logic

```
<xsl:for-each select="Vehicle">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="copyexcludingDL" select=".">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="DriversLicense">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select="DriversLicense" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="DriversLicense">
                <xsl:text>None</xsl:text>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Please add you input XML to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably "not working" because you cannot have an `xsl:choose` as a child of `xsl:apply-templates`.

If your logic is that you want copy the `DriversLicense` node if it exists, but add a default value if it doesn't, then you can achieve by template matching `Vehicle` nodes which have no `DriversLicense` node.

To do this, instead of doing `<xsl:for-each select="Vehicle">`, replace the whole block with an `xsl:apply-templates` instead...

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="Vehicle" />
```

Then add a template that matches `Vehicle` nodes without a `DriversLicense` node, that copies the node and adds a default

```
<xsl:template match="Vehicle[not(DriversLicense)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <DriversLicense>None</DriversLicense>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This assumes you are also using the identity template as well in your XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```